# Undefined reference to `b2world` after installing Box2D with vcpkg

Tags: c++, box2d, vcpkg

I would like to add Box2D to my project using vcpkg but it seems certain files aren't linking.

To do so I run `.\vcpkg install box2d --triplet x64-windows` and copy the values mentioned into my `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
find_package(box2d CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE box2d::box2d)
```

After doing this I can include `box2d/box2d.h`.

```
#include "box2d/box2d.h"

b2Vec2 gravity(0.0f, -10.0f);
b2World world(gravity);
```

However this error is thrown.

```
undefined reference to `b2World::b2World(b2Vec2 const&)'
```

What else am I missing to get this working?

Comment: You should check to see what exact libraries are linked to your executable. This may be a bug in the port file that you should report at the github site.

Comment: Is this question actually a duplicate? The error is the same as mentioned in the referred question however I'm asking about vcpkg and how it isn't right after installing. I don't see how the referred question helps me.

Comment: I am with you , thats a kneejerk duplicated close, without reading the question, you got my vote to reopen. If it doesnt get reopened change the title to something like 'vcpkg fails to find library', sadly I cant help you as I dont know cmake or vcokg very well